# How to read every line of a text file including empty lines

Tags: java, file, filereader

I want to be able to read an entire text file that has empty lines between text. Every solution I try to implement seems to stop reading after it reaches an empty line. I want to be able to read an entire text file, including empty lines, and store the contents in a String. This is what I have now. I included two implementations. How can I alter either of the implementations to continue reading after an empty line? Also, I want the empty lines in the text file to be included in the String that it is being stored in.

```
File templateFile = new File(templatePath);
String oldContent = "";
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(templateFile));

//Implementation 1
String line = reader.readLine();
while(line != null) {
    oldContent = oldContent + line + System.lineSeparator();
    line = reader.readLine();
}



/* Implementation 2
Scanner sc = new Scanner(templateFile);
while(sc.hasNext()) {
    oldContent = sc.nextLine();
} */
```

Comment: Your code works for me. Exactly what do you see?

Comment: My fault. The first implantation is working. The bug was in another method that receives user input.

Answer (score 0):

Using java 11 [`java.nio.file.Files.readString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readString(java.nio.file.Path))

`oldContent = Files.readString(Paths.get(templatePath));`

Comment: @Tim please ask another question about that.